# Ajax form not passing Product Id and Product Title to cart

Tags: django, ajax

I'm following Zander from Very Academy Ecommerce tutorial series and reached the part where we use Ajax to submit form data of the product to the cart.
I've managed to pass the quantity and the price but not the title. Its not rendering(displaying) in  the cart page. Everything else works fine.
I messaged Zander asking for help and its been a month and still no response from him.

Here is the Ajax from the tutorial:

```
  <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#add_button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "inventory:single_product_add_to_cart" %}',
        data: {
          productid: $('#add_button').val(),
          productqty: $('#select option:selected').text(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
          action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {}
      });
    })
  </script>
```

This is my product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    product_metas_set       = models.ForeignKey(ProductMetas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_metas')

    PRODUCT_TYPE            = (
                        ('single_product','Single product'),
                        ('variable_product','Variable product'),
                        ('groupped_product','Groupped product'),
                    )
    PRODUCT_STATUS      = (
                        ('is_inactive','Inactive'),
                        ('is_active','Active'),
                        ('published','Published'),
                    )

    product_status      = models.CharField(choices=PRODUCT_STATUS, max_length=100)

    product_is_featured         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product_is_bestseller       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product_is_on_sale      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    high_sell_through       = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    price_regular       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    price_sale          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    product_UPC             = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_SKU             = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_MODEL_ID        = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    product_stock_management        = models.ForeignKey(ProductStockManagement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_stock_management')


    product_attributes_set      = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttributesSets, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_attributes_set')
    product_specifications_set      = models.ForeignKey(ProductSpecificationsSets, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_specifications_set')
    product_details_list        = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetailsList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_details_list')

    product_variations      = models.ManyToManyField(ProductVariations, blank=True,  max_length=1000)

    category            = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand           = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='brand')
    vendor          = models.ForeignKey('vendors.Vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------


    featured_image      = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCT/FEATURED_IMAGES/', null=True, blank=True)

    image_galley            = models.ForeignKey(ImageGallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_image_gallery')


    #----------------------------------------------------------------


    title           = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=1000)

    description_short       = RichTextField()
    description_full        = RichTextField()

    date_created            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated            = models.DateTimeField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventory:product', args=[self.slug])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is the view file:

```
def single_product_add_to_cart(request):

    cart = Cart(request)
    
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get("productqty"))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

        cart.add(product=product, qty=product_qty)

        cartqty = cart.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({'qty': cartqty})
        
        return response
```

and here is the cart.html page itself:

```
<h2>Cart details:</h2>
<hr>
                
                    
{% if cart %}
  {% for item in cart %}
                {% with product=item.product %}
                        {{product.id}}
                        {{product.title}}
                        {{item.qty}}
                        {{item.price}}<br>
                {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}





                <div class="coupon_section">

                    <form>
                        <input type="text" id="coupon_code" class="coupon_code" name="coupon_code">
                        <button class="apply_coupon" id="apply_coupon" name="apply_coupon">apply coupon</button>
                    </form>
                </div>



            </div>
```

Everything is working, besides the title, why is the title not showing in the cart page when I pass it there--but the price and quantity does?

What am I missing?

**CART CODE:**

```
class CartItems(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)






class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart_items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItems)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def add(self, product):
        self.cart_items = self.cart_items
```

Cart.py

```
class Cart:

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if settings.CART_SESSION_ID not in request.session:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]={}
        self.cart = cart


    def add(self, product, qty):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id]["qty"] = qty
        else:

            self.cart[product_id] = {"price":str(product.price_regular), "qty":qty}

        self.save()


    def update(self, product, qty):


        product_id = str(product)
        
        if product_id in self.basket:
            self.basket[product_id]["qty"] = qty
        self.save()




    def delete():
        pass



    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values()) 



    def __iter__(self):

        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()

        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]["product"] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item["price"] = Decimal(item["price"])
            item["total_price"] = item["price"] * item["qty"]
            yield item







    def get_subtotal(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item["price"]) * item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values())


    def get_grand_total(self):
        newprice = 0.00 
        subtotal = sum(Decimal(item["price"]) * item["qty"] for item in self.cart.values()) 

        if "purchase" in self.session:
            pass 
        total = subtotal + Decimal(newprice)
        return total


    def clear():
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        del self.session["address"]
        del self.session["purchase"]
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True
```

Comment: Can you share the `Cart` code?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem - class CartItems(models.Model):

 product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)

 def __str__(self):
  return str(self.product)






class Cart(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 cart_items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItems)

 def __str__(self):
  return str(self.user)

 def add(self, product):
  self.cart_items = self.cart_items

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem - I don't know how to properly reply with code here-- I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: can you also show the result of `self.cart` (use a print for example) *before* the `__iter__`?

Comment: You also seem to have two `Cart`s? One as model and one that manipulates the `sessions`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " show the result of self.cart before the __iter__". Yes, there is one Cart.py file that manipulates the sessions and cart models. I'm guessing its a mistake.

Comment: I use SQLite, the default django database

Comment: add `print(self.cart)` as first line in the `__iter__` render the tamplate, and share what has been printed. The model is not inherently a problem, but usually it is one of the two, not both.

Comment: I added this "print(self.cart)"  to __iter__, rendered the template and still don't see the title--just the qty and the price.

Comment: this is *not* to fix the problem, but to *diagnose* the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255520/discussion-between-arnold-schwarzkopf-and-willem-van-onsem).